# Prove that a set S in n space is compact if and only if every sequence in S has a limit point that belongs to S.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

this is a question from *Advanced Calculus* by Robert Creighton Buck.
I manage to do the forward direction, but I am completely lost in the backward direction. Please help me how to formulate the proof

Comment: Welcome to MSE :D would you mind showing some of your work? Perhaps your method of attack for "the backward direction"?

Comment: I'd guess a proof by contradiction might work. Somehow you'll be able to construct a set of points not covered by a finite subcover.

Comment: Hi, so far I am thinking about that since every sequence has a limit point, then it must have a convergent subsequence. Hence it is bounded, so I was thinking about showing that it is bounded and closed, implying compactness. However, I am still thinking how to prove it is closed.

Comment: It may be useful to remember that every limit point is in the closure of a set.

Answer (score 0):

First show by contradiction that S is bounded.
Secondly use a theorem that shows S is closed.
Thus by the Heine Weierstrass theorem or a corrollary thereof,
S is compact.

Comment: Do you mean Heine-Borel or Bolzano-Weierstrass?

Comment: The theorem that a bounded closed subset of R^n is compact.